# Sonata sontauser and fosuser

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I am trying to use sonata as my backed. I am now trying to set up some users.
I have installed the fosuserbundle but when I try to get sonata-project/user-bundle I get this:

```
  Problem 1
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.2 requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.2.7 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.1 requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.2.7 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.0 requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.2.7 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.6.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.6.x-dev].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.6.x-dev requires sonata-project/user-bundle ~2.2 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4].
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.3 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev].
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.4 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle 1.3.x-dev
```

I was looking at the sonata sandbox and in the AppKernel.php they have the following:

```
        // USER
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
        new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
```

I can't find the requirement for FOSUserBundle in their composer file.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I just want to have a simple admin with user management so that I can have something that requires logged in users to access.

Using:
PHP 5.4.36-0+deb7u1 (cli)
Symfony 2.6.3

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have followed HypeR suggestion and I now have the correct bundles.

There is a problem with the login. I have created the application bundle and it expects a fos_user_user table. How do I create this??

I try to login and get an error saying that the table fos_user_user does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the installation documentation on how to install [SonataUserBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html).

To have user management, you need to install [FosUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/index.md). At the moment Sonata doesn't support the last version of FosUserBundle that's why you have to install the 1.3 version. There is more details about that on this [issue](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/322).

Then you need to install the 2 dependencies of SonataUserBundle : [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/installation.html) & [SonataEasyExtendsBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/reference/installation.html).

Then you can follow the install documentation of SonataUserBundle.

Good luck !

**Update**

It seems that your database is missing some tables, you should go in the root directory of your project and do in command line :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

You can check the mysql queries that are about to be executed with the --force by using :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Check if you did all the steps of the installation of FOSUserBundle 1.3 : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: Regarding update: Yes that was the missing step. Thanks! One quick question. In the sonata demo there is an admin area for users is that something I can activate or is it a feature of only the sonata demo?

Comment: SonataUserBundle has an integrated Admin (https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/tree/master/Admin), you should have a User and Group Admin if you follow the installation step of SonataUserBundle : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html

Comment: I did follow the docs but I am not seeing any links in the side menu nor in the admin.group blocks

Comment: Never mind last comment. I customized the dasboard.groups and that seemed to remove the user stuff. Is there any way for me to customize the side menu and have the user stuff? Thanks again

Comment: I looked into the sonata demo and figured it out. Thanks again for the help. If I could give more +1 I would :)

Comment: Thanks ! Happy to help and give some advices on Sonata :)